# Share adhoc connection with Playstation 3

Tags: networking, 3g, ps3, adhoc

I'm using a mobile internet connection on my Ubuntu laptop, and I'm sharing it (wlan) using adhoc. The problem seems to be that it only works using WEP security, but my PS3 can not connect to, or even find, the shared wireless network.

I've tried using both "WEP 128-bit Passphrase" and "WEP 40/128-bit Key (Hex or ASCII)", but niether works.

Is there something I can do to share my connection using WPA or is there an other solution?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: @fossfreedom Umm, what more information do you want? The OP described the network setup (Mobile -> Laptop -> Adhoc -> PS3), described the encryption, and asked why the PS3 can't find it. That's plenty of information for a potential answerer. And unless old=closed now, this should be open